# Disable line from tooltip to point location on the chart

Tags: highcharts

When you position the tooltip "absolutely" by specifying the positioner, the line extending from the point position to the tooltip becomes annoying. How to disable this? (I have also specified a formatter, and using shared - but evidently it is highcharts that decide to include the line when the number of visible series == 1).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the shape of a tooltip - by default it is a callout which has an anchor for pointing a point. Rect shape does not have any anchors.

```
    tooltip: {
        positioner: function () {
            return { x: 80, y: 50 };
        },
        shape: 'rect',
        shared: true
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/7r7wrysL/